# Is there a pattern for writting telescopic configureable classes in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm thinking at the moment about the solution of a problem which might be already solved by a pattern but I can not find the correct one. I'll try to explain what I would like to do with a simplefied example.

There is a class which handles to connection to a database, let's call it DatabaseManager.java. With this class I would like to handle the fetchment of data from a database and I also would like to apply filter.

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    DatabaseFilter databaseFilter = new DatabaseFilter();

    public DatabaseManager() {
        // Do some stuff to init db connection
    }

    public DatabaseFilter configureFilter() {
        return databaseFilter;
    }

    public String getStringDataset() {
        String dataset = null;
        // Fill dataset with applied filter data
        return dataset;
    }

}
```

With the method call configureFilter() on the databse object, I would like to get the DatabaseFilter which contains particular nested filter classes.

```
public class DatabaseFilter {

    int[] filteredIds = null;

    public IdFilter onId() {
        return new IdFilter();
    }

    public class IdFilter {
        private void exclude(int[] ids) {
            filteredIds = ids;
        }
    }
}
```

On this way, I could write the follwing nice syntax to configure a filter which excludes particular filter.

```
DatabaseManager database = new DatabaseManager();
database.configureFilter().onId().exclude(idArray);
// Get filtered dataset
database.getStringDataset();
```

Is this an appropriate way to solve problems like this and is this a particular pattern? Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: It's called a Builder pattern or Adapter Pattern with a Fluent API

Comment: Have you tried builder pattern? You can find a good example here https://www.journaldev.com/1425/builder-design-pattern-in-java scroll towards then end to see the usage of class that implements builder pattern

Comment: If you're looking for is a nice syntax, there are plenty of libraries that allow you to query a database like that. The filtering makes me think of Hibernate's filtering mechanisms. So you're not inventing anything new here, but whether you're using the right tool for the right job is unclear. The code you're displaying doesn't look very elegant with manually excluding `ids` and getting a "string dataset". What do you think would be the advantages of this approach?

Comment: Also check http://www.querydsl.com/ for some fluent API inspiration

Comment: @Kayaman
I'm actutally using Hibernate as ORM and I'm not building simple filter where I just filter on a Id. I also quering a whole Entity and not just a String. Thats why I called it a simplified version. I also considered using hibernate criteria querys, however at one point this filters need to be configured.

Comment: If you ask a question where you describe a simplified version that has nothing to do with what you're actually trying to accomplish, we have no way of giving you proper advice. Edit the question to better show what you're trying to do, so far the question doesn't make much sense and is unanswerable.